# How to fix Ubuntu from logging into weird "simple GNOME" as I call it

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gdm

I was trying to fix ubuntu because the wifi was not working. It wouldn't allow me to control networking, and it said I had no privileges to so this. Lately, most of the stuff on my ubuntu OS screwed up, and it was all after the software update. So anyways, I went online and tried to figure out a solution for my wifi problem. I found out that if I typed in `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` my wifi problem would be fixed. So after I tried that, and rebooted, I went into UBUNTU 14.04 in grub, and all that came up was a black screen and the date and time at the top. It looked a little like GNOME, except all I could do was look at the date and time. PLS HELP...

---

*By the way, I'm a tech **noob**.*

I can provide an example, but it's not the real thing. It's what I created in an image editor, but it looks similar to it.

[image: Image Example of my predicament]

Comment: `gdm` probably isn't even installed. You can install it if you like, or go back to `lightdm`: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. There's no reason why messing about with the display manager would get your Wi-Fi working. Failing that, you'll probably need to purge all the config files that have been screwed up and reinstall. No way to tell from here.

Comment: @KenSharp I can't get a terminal up and running, because there isn't much of a GUI except for the date/time.

Comment: Ctr+Alt+F1 should get you to tty1

Comment: @SuperSluether How does this help me?

Comment: Uh... Because it gets you to a terminal? Because you said you couldn't get to one because the GUI was broken?

Comment: @SuperSluether Oh, i thought that if you had to get to terminal, you had to do ctrl + alt + t. Thanks!

Comment: @SuperSluether Sorry, but this didn't help me very much. The screen doesn't do anything. The only (sorta working) functions are wifi (it says it connected, but obviously I have no Chrome to use it.) date and time ( wrong time) and screenshot by pressing the 'print screen' button, but obviously, I have no GUI to view it.